# What do the letters W, Z and G stand for on an extension cord (USA)?

Tags: ac, symbol

G seems to be obviously (G)round, but I have no idea which of the others is Neutral and which is Hot.

[image]

Comment: What country???

Comment: Zwart = Black in Dutch. Could this be South African (Afrikaans)  by any chance? Do they use NEMA connectors like the USA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

North American Standard

W, White,  Neutral
Z , Black, Hot (120Vac/60Hz)
G,  Green, Earth Ground

WJ-28-1
NEMA 1-15P  SPT-2(wire)     18-16/2C  AWG

### Updated  P/N

thanks to david

**WJ-23-1**     [5-15P  SJT/W   18-12/3C](http://productspec.ul.com/canada/document.php?id=ELBZ7.E301276)

E301276
JIANDE WANJIA ELECTRICAL APPLIANCE & CABLE CO.,LTD.
INDUSTRIAL ZONE SOUTH OF BRIDGE, MEICHENG JIANDE
HANGZHOU, CHINA

Comment: Looks like the model number is WJ-23-1 from the picture, which the cUL certification directory shows as 5-15P (http://database.ul.com/cgi-bin/XYV/template/LISEXT/1FRAME/showpage.html?name=ELBZ7.E301276&ccnshorttitle=Cord+Sets+and+Power-supply+Cords+Certified+for+Canada&objid=1077969873&cfgid=1073741824&version=versionless&parent_id=1073986174&sequence=1)

Comment: 1-15P is incorrect since the pictured plug includes a ground pin. 1-15P is two prongs only.